# exporting attribute tables of multiple rasters to excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, attribute-table, export, excel

I had a raster and I clipped it using a shapefile of polygons. Now I have about 5500 individual raster images. I have to export the attribute table of each raster to excel so that I can then append them and make a new dataset in excel. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You have an ArcPy tag but have not included a code snippet of what you have tried so far.  Did you use ArcPy to perform your clipping?

Comment: If you want to take attributes from one (or many) rasters and add them to another different raster you can do that easier by using cursors. From your explanation, you want to take one attribute from RasterA and copy the attribute to RasterB? Would you show what are you trying to achieve? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [page](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/84698), I think the code provided in that page is similar to what you are trying to achieve. Once you are done with creating csv files or text files, you can merge them easily into one single file in python. From my personal experince, I would suggest you to stay away from excel as your columns can get truncated depending on whether you use *.xls or *.xlsx format.